# How to modify existing plugin in a Phonegap project?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

In phone gap development we have to use plugin for do platform specific task, we can find lot of open source plugins from internet.

my problems are

1. how to customise existing plugin's classes ?
2. how to add new class for existing plugin ?

Comment: what platform you use right now?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I'm currently using iOS and want to use other flatform also..